# Bokeh Multi line plots doesn't show

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I have a dataframe like below

```
    data_date  created_time  order_number
0  2017-02-01         00:00           204
1  2017-02-01         10:00            85
2  2017-02-02         20:00            73
3  2017-02-02         13:00            79
4  2017-02-03         14:00           166
```

So what I want to do is to visualize the booking amount in hourly basis each day . The line plot will differ based on the data_date column, so there should be 3 lines on the graph.

Here is the code I made with bokeh library

```
source = ColumnDataSource(hourly_booking)
colormap = CategoricalColorMapper(factors=hourly_booking['data_date'].unique(), palette=['red', 'green', 'blue'])
p = figure(x_axis_label = 'Time (24-Hour)', y_axis_label = 'Amount of order')
p.multi_line(xs='created_booking', ys='order_number', source=source, line_color=dict(field='data_date', transform=colormap), line_width=5, line_alpha=0.6, legend='data_date')

output_file('graph.html')
show(p)
```

However the page goes blank so I don't know what went wrong with the codes.

[image]

What should I do?
Any suggestion would be appreciated :)

Comment: Looks like there's something wrong with your ColumnDataSource object. Is 'hourly_booking' the dataframe you printed above or did you do any further processing before passing it to  'source = ColumnDataSource(hourly_booking)'?

Comment: Additionally is `data_date` those actual strings? Or are they date(time) objects? Categorical color mapper only operates on string categories.

Comment: @Automaton2000 Yes it is and no further process on the dataframe

Comment: @bigreddot they are date time
if I use circle plot, it works :(

Comment: I just noticed this was `multi_line` your data is not in the right format at all for `multi_line`. Since it draws *multiple lines* the data provided has to be a *list of lists* (or arrays) where each sublist is for one of the separate lines. You are just giving one 1-d pandas series. I'd suggest just making separate calls to `line` for each subset you want to plot. If you really want to use `multi_line` the docs have an example of that data format: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#multiple-lines